# How to prevent page to scroll to top after gridview checkbox changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G95zF.png)i tried many solutions before to prevent page scroll top after checkbox in grid view was changed but no one solve my problem .. please help!
thanks in advance

(update)-->

### this is the Design code:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="Panel" GroupingText="<img src='Images/lightbulb.gif' /> Step 2: Seclect Threats to detect">
                                        <%--<h1 style="text-align:right;padding-right:30px;position:absolute;right:40px;top:300px" > <asp:Label ID="lbl_cost" runat="server" Text="0 $" ></asp:Label></h1>--%>
                                        <ajax:TabContainer ID="tc_thread_types" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" CssClass="Tab" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                                            <ajax:TabPanel ID="tab_mem_threads" runat="server" HeaderText="Member Threats" CssClass="Tab">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                     <div id="scrollDiv1" style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px; overflow: auto" >
                                                        <asp:GridView ID="gv_ThDetails_Mem" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" 
                                                                      Style="width: 100%; padding: 25px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" 
                                                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gv_ThDetails_mem_RowDataBound">
                                                            <Columns>

                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="thread_id" HeaderText="Threat Id" />
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="thread_desc" HeaderText="Threat Description" />
                                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ch_all_mem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ch_all_mem_CheckedChanged" />
                                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                 <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_includedThreat_mem1" Onclick='<%# "ShowCurrentTime(" +Eval("serial") + " );" %>' runat="server" />--%>
                                                                 <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_includedThreat_mem" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cb_includedThreat_mem_CheckedChanged" />

                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="serial" HeaderText="serial" Visible="false" />
                                                            </Columns>
                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                    </div>
                                                   <script type="text/javascript">


                                                       //var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();


                                                       //prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);


                                                       //function beginRequest() {
                                                       //    prm._scrollPosition = null;
                                                       //}


                                                    </script>

                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </ajax:TabPanel>
 </ajax:TabContainer>
```

### And this is the code behind:

```
protected void cb_includedThreat_mem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //up_frdSetup.Update();

            CheckBox included = (CheckBox)sender;
            //GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)included.Parent.Parent;

            int count;

            if (rbl_memType.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                included.Checked = false;
                SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("U6", "You should select membership first!");    // casting
                SystemMsg.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (Session["IsExpired"] != null && Session["IsExpired"].ToString().Equals("Y") && rbl_memType.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("T"))
            {
                included.Checked = false;
                ib_save.Enabled = false;
               // ib_save.CssClass = "btn disabled";
                ib_save.ToolTip = "Submit was disabled As your trial version was expired!";
                SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("U6", "Your trial version was expired! Please select Preimuim Subscription Now!");
                //lbl_cln_msg.Text = "Your trial version was expired! Please select Premium Subscription Now!";
                //cln_msg.Style.Add("display", "normal");
                return;
            }


            if (ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] == null)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count = int.Parse(ViewState["cnt_th_mem"].ToString());
            }


            if (included.Checked)
            {
                count++;
                ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] = count;
            }
            else if (!included.Checked && count > 0)
            {
                count--;
                ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] = count;
            }
            included.Focus();


            if (rbl_memType.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("T"))
            {
                int tot_cnt = fn_check_tot_checked_threads();

                if (tot_cnt > 3)
                {
                    included.Checked = false;
                    count--;
                    ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] = count;
                    //lbl_cln_msg.Text = "The Maximum allowed threats in trial membership is Three only!";
                    //cln_msg.Style.Add("display", "normal");
                    SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("U6", "The Maximum allowed threats in trial membership is Three only!");
                    SystemMsg.Focus();
                    return;
                }
                //lbl_cost.Text = "0$";
                //ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] = 0;
            }
            else if (rbl_memType.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("P"))
            {
                //lbl_cost.Text = (Double.Parse(Session["th_price"].ToString()) * count) + "$";
                ViewState["cnt_th_mem"] = count;
            }

            //fn_checkIncluded_Mem_Threads();

            CheckBox ch_all = gv_ThDetails_Mem.HeaderRow.FindControl("ch_all_mem") as CheckBox;
            if (count == gv_ThDetails_Mem.Rows.Count)
            {
                ch_all.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (count == 0)
            {
                ch_all.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ch_all.Checked = false;                
            }
            fn_check_tot_cost();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException eio)
        {
            SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("S1", eio.Message);    // IO
            SystemMsg.Focus();
            return;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("S2", ex.Message);    // NULL
            SystemMsg.Focus();
            return;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("S4", sqlEx.Message);    // SQL
            SystemMsg.Focus();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            SystemMsg.fn_SetMessageProperties("S0", exe.Message);
            SystemMsg.Focus();
            return;
        }

}
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Well, is your checkbox causing a `post`? Really hard to say or suggest anything without code.

Comment: Share your code and if possible, a screenshot.

Comment: @HanletEscaño if you mean 'postback' then Yes

Comment: @AT-2016 Done
when i check a checkbox in grid view , page scroll  top!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the page directive **<%@ Page %>**

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = "true"
```

It happens due to page PostBack. The above ensures the position of the scroll after page PostBack.

Or keep the `GridView` in a div and use `JavaScript` trick to do so: [Maintain Scroll Position in Div](http://michaelsync.net/2006/06/30/maintain-scroll-position-of-div-using-javascript-aspnet-20)

Comment: sorry .. i clicked enter before end my comment...i tried this solution before but it does not work

Comment: Glad to know :D